# Has anyone used any .Net code generation frameworks in Mono? (Subsonic, .netTiers, etc..)

Tags: nhibernate, subsonic, mono, code-generation, .nettiers

Mono appears to have really come a log way since the last time I really used it.  I'm interested in doing some ASP.Net development using Mono.  I have used .netTiers/CodeSmith at work and really enjoy the speed with which code generation gives you a clean working data access layer.  The question is has anybody used any code generation with Mono? I am open to learning something like SubSonic or NHibernate if those work better with Mono.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This question has been asked ad infinitum. Did you do a search ? site:stackoverflow.com NHibernate Code Generation Mono ?

Answer (score 2):

I have used subsonic with mono. I've used it on mono 2.0, on which SubStage (GUI front end for subsonic ) does not work, but you can generate code using command line option. It works very well with mono. I don't find any problem while using SubSonic generated code in mono.

I have not NHibernate on mono. NHibernate  is very complex, I tried to learn it, but give. While SubSonic is very easy, it take me less than 1hr to learn SubSonic.

If you are interested in Linq, I suggest to you give a try to [DBLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) , DBLinq team is working with Mono team to implement Linq to Sql in Mono.

Comment: I'm trying to use SubSonic with mono.  I can get it to generate files for each of my tables, but the files are empty.  I suspect it's having trouble finding my templates directory, but I'm not sure.  Did you have any problem like this?

Comment: I have not come across problem like this, please check parameters. What is in log? Try to run Gui (SubCommander) under mono.

Answer (score 0):

This link describes it pretty well. Not entirely sure I understand it, but the end result is good performance.
http://www.mono-project.com/Linear_IL

Answer (score 0):

We do have people using [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) to generate code that runs under Mono. I talked to one guy who was creating a Mono Framework with CodeSmith.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski